# Required Field for Comment parent only?

Tags: comments

I am trying to make the rating required for a comment but not required when it is a reply.  Its not working, can you please help.

```
function custom_validate_comment() {
    //validate rating
    if( $comment->comment_parent==0) { 
    if( empty( $_POST['rating'])  )
            wp_die( __('Error: Please Include Your Rating (0 to 5 Stars)')    );
    }
}

add_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'custom_validate_comment');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$comment` is not set inside that function. Look into [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

`$_POST['comment_parent']` should be set though.

```
function custom_validate_comment() {
    //validate rating
    if( isset($_POST['comment_parent']) && $_POST['comment_parent'] === 0) { 
    if( empty( $_POST['rating'])  )
            wp_die( __('Error: Please Include Your Rating (0 to 5 Stars)')    );
    }
}
add_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'custom_validate_comment');
```

You could also rewrite your function to take a parameter-- `function custom_validate_comment($comment_id)`-- and then use [`get_comment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment) to grab information about that comment but since the parent is passed in the `$_POST` data (I checked), I don't see the point of that step.

Comment: If the answer solved the problem, please "Accept" it.